# merging list of lists together with different dimention lengths

Tags: r

I have a list of lists which I am trying to "merge" together.

The dimentions are:

```
> dim(lst$`63908`$information)
[1]  1 19
> dim(lst$`63908`$filings)
[1] 27 11


> dim(lst$`793952`$information)
[1]  1 19
> dim(lst$`793952`$filings)
[1] 27 11


> dim(lst$`894405`$information)
[1]  1 19
> dim(lst$`894405`$filings)
[1] 27 11
```

I am trying to join `information` and `filings` for each company (or number) in the list. I want to map or join the `information` list to the `filings` list so I will have 1 list for each company and the `information` list will be repeated `27` times which is the length of the `filings` list. How can I proceed with this?

New Data:

```
lst2 <- list(`43410` = list(information = structure(list(name = "GREAT NORTHERN IRON ORE PROPERTIES", 
    cik = "0000043410", fiscal_year_end = "1231", company_href = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000043410&owner=exclude&count=100", 
    sic = "6795", sic_description = "MINERAL ROYALTY TRADERS", 
    state_location = "MN", state_incorporation = "MN", mailing_city = "ST PAUL", 
    mailing_state = "MN", mailing_zip = "55101-1361", mailing_street = "W 1290 FIRST NATIONAL BANK BLDG", 
    mailing_street2 = "332 MINNESOTA STREET", business_city = "SAINT PAUL", 
    business_state = "MN", business_zip = "55101-1361", business_street = "W 1290 FIRST NATIONAL BANK BLDG", 
    business_street2 = "332 MINNESOTA ST", business_phone = "6122242385"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame"), filings = structure(list(accession_number = c("0000897101-15-000249", 
"0000897101-14-000198", "0000897101-13-000217", "0000897101-12-000229", 
"0000897101-11-000241", "0000897101-10-000259", "0000897101-09-000357", 
"0000897101-08-000407", "0000897101-07-000419", "0000897101-06-000431", 
"0000897101-05-000553", "0000897101-04-000395", "0000897101-03-000189", 
"0000897101-02-000168", "0000897101-01-000229", "0000897101-00-000219", 
"0000897101-99-000213", "0000897101-98-000278", "0000897101-97-000272", 
"0000897101-96-000096"), act = c("34", "34", "34", "34", "34", 
"34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), file_number = c("001-00701", "001-00701", "001-00701", 
"001-00701", "001-00701", "001-00701", "001-00701", "001-00701", 
"001-00701", "001-00701", "001-00701", "001-00701", "001-00701", 
"001-00701", "001-00701", "001-00701", "001-00701", "001-00701", 
"001-00701", "001-00701"), filing_date = structure(c(1424905200, 
1392850800, 1361487600, 1329433200, 1297983600, 1266447600, 1235602800, 
1204066800, 1172185200, 1140735600, 1109286000, 1077750000, 1047596400, 
1016146800, 984092400, 952642800, 921193200, 889743600, 858294000, 
826239600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), accepted_date = structure(c(1424905200, 
1392850800, 1361487600, 1329433200, 1297983600, 1266447600, 1235602800, 
1204066800, 1172185200, 1140735600, 1109286000, 1077750000, 1047596400, 
1016146800, 984092400, 952642800, 921193200, 889743600, 858294000, 
826239600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), href = c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710115000249/0000897101-15-000249-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710114000198/0000897101-14-000198-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710113000217/0000897101-13-000217-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710112000229/0000897101-12-000229-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710111000241/0000897101-11-000241-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710110000259/0000897101-10-000259-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710109000357/0000897101-09-000357-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710108000407/0000897101-08-000407-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710107000419/0000897101-07-000419-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710106000431/0000897101-06-000431-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710105000553/0000897101-05-000553-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710104000395/0000897101-04-000395-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710103000189/0000897101-03-000189-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710102000168/0000897101-02-000168-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/000089710101000229/0000897101-01-000229-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/0000897101-00-000219-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/0000897101-99-000213-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/0000897101-98-000278-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/0000897101-97-000272-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/43410/0000897101-96-000096-index.html"
), type = c("10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", 
"10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K405", "10-K405", 
"10-K405", "10-K405", "10-K405", "10-K405", "10-K405"), film_number = c("15651558", 
"14628861", "13633190", "12621778", "11623572", "10615446", "09636574", 
"08645305", "07644168", "06641277", "05639391", "04629089", "03603149", 
"02576043", "1564399", "565431", "99563708", "98564913", "97556531", 
"96532494"), form_name = c("Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]"), description = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    size = c("5 MB", "5 MB", "3 MB", "1 MB", "1 MB", "1 MB", 
    "1 MB", "1 MB", "1 MB", "514 KB", "493 KB", "525 KB", "168 KB", 
    "147 KB", "142 KB", "135 KB", "137 KB", "132 KB", "128 KB", 
    "132 KB")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")), 
    `854099` = list(information = structure(list(name = "SURGICAL LASER TECHNOLOGIES INC /DE/", 
        cik = "0000854099", fiscal_year_end = "0103", company_href = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000854099&owner=exclude&count=100", 
        sic = "3845", sic_description = "ELECTROMEDICAL &amp; ELECTROTHERAPEUTIC APPARATUS", 
        state_location = "PA", state_incorporation = "DE", mailing_city = "MONTGOMERYVILLE", 
        mailing_state = "PA", mailing_zip = "18936", mailing_street = "147 KEYSTONE DRIVE", 
        mailing_street2 = NA_character_, business_city = "MONTGOMERYVILLE", 
        business_state = "PA", business_zip = "18936", business_street = "147 KEYSTONE DRIVE", 
        business_street2 = NA_character_, business_phone = "6106500700"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), filings = structure(list(accession_number = c("0000950154-02-000122", 
    "0000950154-01-500166", "0000950115-00-000365", "0000950115-99-000493", 
    "0000950115-98-000504", "0000950115-97-000529", "0000950115-97-000492", 
    "0000950115-96-001251", "0000950115-96-000320"), act = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), file_number = c("000-17919", "000-17919", "000-17919", 
    "000-17919", "000-17919", "000-17919", "000-17919", "000-17919", 
    "000-17919"), filing_date = structure(c(1017356400, 985903200, 
    953766000, 922917600, 890780400, 860364000, 859759200, 841183200, 
    828309600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
        accepted_date = structure(c(1017356400, 985903200, 953766000, 
        922917600, 890780400, 860364000, 859759200, 841183200, 
        828309600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
        href = c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/854099/000095015402000122/0000950154-02-000122-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/854099/000095015401500166/0000950154-01-500166-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/854099/0000950115-00-000365-index.html", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/854099/0000950115-99-000493-index.html", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/854099/0000950115-98-000504-index.html", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/854099/0000950115-97-000529-index.html", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/854099/0000950115-97-000492-index.html", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/854099/0000950115-96-001251-index.html", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/854099/0000950115-96-000320-index.html"
        ), type = c("10-K", "10-K", "10-K405", "10-K", "10-K405", 
        "10-K405/A", "10-K405", "10-K/A", "10-K"), film_number = c("02593792", 
        "1587034", "576973", "99586150", "98573043", "97576026", 
        "97571667", "96622343", "96542736"), form_name = c("Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]"
        ), description = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_), size = c("194 KB", "209 KB", 
        "224 KB", "235 KB", "261 KB", "185 KB", "187 KB", "234 KB", 
        "206 KB")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")), 
    `1024125` = list(information = structure(list(name = "CRAGAR INDUSTRIES INC /DE", 
        cik = "0001024125", fiscal_year_end = "1231", company_href = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001024125&owner=exclude&count=100", 
        sic = "3714", sic_description = "MOTOR VEHICLE PARTS &amp; ACCESSORIES", 
        state_location = "AZ", state_incorporation = "DE", mailing_city = "PHOENIX", 
        mailing_state = "AZ", mailing_zip = "85031", mailing_street = "4636 N. 43RD AVE", 
        mailing_street2 = NA_character_, business_city = "PHOENIX", 
        business_state = "AZ", business_zip = "85031", business_street = "4336 N. 43RD AVE", 
        business_street2 = NA_character_, business_phone = "6022471300"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), filings = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), class = "data.frame", row.names = integer(0))), 
    `712515` = list(information = structure(list(name = "ELECTRONIC ARTS INC.", 
        cik = "0000712515", fiscal_year_end = "0331", company_href = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000712515&owner=exclude&count=100", 
        sic = "7372", sic_description = "SERVICES-PREPACKAGED SOFTWARE", 
        state_location = "CA", state_incorporation = "DE", mailing_city = "REDWOOD CITY", 
        mailing_state = "CA", mailing_zip = "94065", mailing_street = "209 REDWOOD SHORES PARKWAY", 
        mailing_street2 = NA_character_, business_city = "REDWOOD CITY", 
        business_state = "CA", business_zip = "94065", business_street = "209 REDWOOD SHORES PARKWAY", 
        business_street2 = NA_character_, business_phone = "650-628-1500"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), filings = structure(list(accession_number = c("0000712515-18-000024", 
    "0000712515-17-000035", "0000712515-16-000111", "0000712515-15-000033", 
    "0000712515-14-000049", "0000712515-14-000024", "0000712515-13-000022", 
    "0001193125-12-249324", "0001193125-11-149262", "0000950130-10-001579", 
    "0001193125-09-116895", "0000891618-08-000290", "0000950134-07-012528", 
    "0000950134-06-011401", "0000891618-05-000406", "0000891618-04-001046", 
    "0000891618-03-002939", "0001012870-02-002877", "0000950005-01-500255", 
    "0000950005-00-000876", "0000950005-00-000777", "0000950005-99-000599", 
    "0000950005-98-000571", "0001012870-97-001195", "0000912057-96-013563", 
    "0000912057-95-004984"), act = c("34", "34", "34", "34", 
    "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", 
    "34", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), file_number = c("000-17948", 
    "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", 
    "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", 
    "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", 
    "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", 
    "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948", "000-17948"
    ), filing_date = structure(c(1527026400, 1495576800, 1464300000, 
    1432159200, 1412287200, 1400623200, 1369173600, 1337896800, 
    1306188000, 1274997600, 1242943200, 1211493600, 1180476000, 
    1150063200, 1118095200, 1086300000, 1055196000, 1025215200, 
    993765600, 965944800, 962229600, 930607200, 898812000, 867016800, 
    836172000, 804376800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
        accepted_date = structure(c(1527026400, 1495576800, 1464213600, 
        1432159200, 1412287200, 1400623200, 1369173600, 1337896800, 
        1306188000, 1274997600, 1242856800, 1211493600, 1180389600, 
        1149804000, 1118095200, 1086300000, 1055196000, 1025215200, 
        993765600, 965944800, 962229600, 930607200, 898812000, 
        867016800, 836172000, 804376800), class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), href = c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000071251518000024/0000712515-18-000024-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000071251517000035/0000712515-17-000035-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000071251516000111/0000712515-16-000111-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000071251515000033/0000712515-15-000033-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000071251514000049/0000712515-14-000049-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000071251514000024/0000712515-14-000024-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000071251513000022/0000712515-13-000022-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000119312512249324/0001193125-12-249324-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000119312511149262/0001193125-11-149262-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000095013010001579/0000950130-10-001579-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000119312509116895/0001193125-09-116895-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000089161808000290/0000891618-08-000290-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000095013407012528/0000950134-07-012528-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000095013406011401/0000950134-06-011401-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000089161805000406/0000891618-05-000406-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000089161804001046/0000891618-04-001046-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000089161803002939/0000891618-03-002939-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000101287002002877/0001012870-02-002877-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000095000501500255/0000950005-01-500255-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000095000500000876/0000950005-00-000876-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/000095000500000777/0000950005-00-000777-index.htm", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/0000950005-99-000599-index.html", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/0000950005-98-000571-index.html", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/0001012870-97-001195-index.html", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/0000912057-96-013563-index.html", 
        "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/712515/0000912057-95-004984-index.html"
        ), type = c("10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K/A", 
        "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", 
        "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", 
        "10-K/A", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K405"
        ), film_number = c("18855472", "17867170", "161679738", 
        "15883321", "141140195", "14861211", "13865105", "12871782", 
        "11868579", "10867459", "09846699", "08859043", "07885284", 
        "06898280", "05882947", "04850503", "03739506", "02691823", 
        "1671648", "694392", "663928", "99655069", "98655515", 
        "97627835", "96589370", "95550463"), form_name = c("Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
        "Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]"
        ), description = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), size = c("15 MB", 
        "14 MB", "15 MB", "21 MB", "934 KB", "26 MB", "21 MB", 
        "14 MB", "17 MB", "5 MB", "2 MB", "1 MB", "1 MB", "1 MB", 
        "1 MB", "1 MB", "1 MB", "900 KB", "1 MB", "7 KB", "412 KB", 
        "716 KB", "226 KB", "568 KB", "197 KB", "431 KB")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -26L), class = "data.frame")))
```

Comment: What are the columns by which it should be merged

Comment: If you meant to just row bind the datasets together, try `library(tidyverse);lst %>% transpose %>% map(bind_rows)`

Comment: I think that "might" be what I am after, however when I run `out <- plyr::ldply(x, data.frame)` I get a lot of NA values

Comment: Because you are merging different datasets together in the `ldply`.  You get a single data.frame as output.  However, in my version, I am transposing the datasets within the list so that all the 'filings' and 'information' are each in a single list which is then binded together with bind_rows

Comment: I am trying to merge the `information` and `filings` into one list for each ID. The structure of the list currently goes:  `lst --> 63908 --> list(information, filings)` and I am trying to get it something like: `lst --> 63908 --> merged(information, filings)`. Does that make sense? So finally I will have `lst --> 63908 --> all_items`.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.  With the `transpose` step, you will get `list(information, information)` for different ids, and similarity for `list(filings, filings)` .  Remember that when you do rbind datasets with different column names, those column that doesn't exist will show value `NA`

Comment: If you do `lst %>% transpose %>% map_df(bind_rows)` it will be a single dataframe

Comment: Is it possible to "fill out" the list of `27 (filings)` list with the list of `1 information` list? So I will have the columns in `information` such as `name, cik, fiscal_year_end` 27 times then just merge the two lists together?

Comment: Not clear about the expected output.  It would have been better if the example is a small example along with expected output for that example

Comment: I will add an edit to the original post to explain a little more clearly now.

Comment: Did you meant `map2_df(map(lst, pluck, 'information'), map(lst, pluck, 'filings'), cbind)`

Comment: Or compactly `map_df(lst,  ~ { cbind(.x[['information']], .x[['filings']]) })`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want! Thanks! However it breaks when the lengths of the list differ. I Will add 3 new data points.

Comment: Did you meant that some 'id's are not having 'information' or 'filings'?

Comment: I have added some new data, some have zero observations others have 9, or 20 observations.

Comment: `map2_df(map(lst2, pluck, 'information'), map(lst2, pluck, 'filings'), ~ if(is.null(.y)) .x else cbind(.x, .y))` works for your new example

Comment: Thanks! It worked for the sample I Will run it on a bit more data and let you know how it goes. Thanks again I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are cases of `NULL` elements, one approach would be to `pluck` the 'information' and 'filings' separately, convert to single data.frame with an `id` column and do a `full_join` (assuming that the 'information' element have either 1 or 0 rows.

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(lst2, pluck, 'information', .id  = 'id') %>% 
     full_join(map_df(lst2, pluck, 'filings', .id = 'id'), by = 'id')
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(purrr)
foo <- map(lst, function(x) { map_at(x, "information", function(y){map(y, rep, 27)})})
bar <- foo %>% map(flatten)

# if you want info about each company as a dataframe
bar2 <- bar  %>% map(as.data.frame)
```

Comment: Done. Sorry I forgot about that.

Comment: Thanks for this! As I have just written to Akrun, is it posible to apply this to lists of different lengths? (I have added some new data to represent this)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to handle lists of different lengths:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
lst2$`1024125` <- NULL
lst2 %>%
  map(function(x) {cbind.data.frame(x) %>% fill(everything())}) -> lst3
```

Take notice that I am discarding element `1024125` from list `lst2`. That list element contains an empty dataframe with not columns whatsoever. I think you should tidy your data first and make sure that all those dataframes have at least the same columns, i.e. all `information` dataframes have the same columns, and all `filings` dataframes have the same columns.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a base R solution to extract needed sublists and `cbind` items together with `Map`. Then a final `do.call(rbind, ...)` outside loop for single final data frame output.

Because there are empty data frames in *filings*, an extended function handler is needed to add empty columns for successfully `rbind` append at end. Below even creates an ID column using names of one of the sublist:

```
# EXTRACT NEEDED SUB LISTS
info_list <- lapply(lst2, `[[`, "information")
filings_list <- lapply(lst2, `[[`, "filings")

proc_merge <- function(i, f, n) {
  if(nrow(f) == 0) {
    # FILL EMPTY COLUMNS WITH NA
    i[colnames(filings_list[[1]])] <- NA
    df <- cbind(ID=n, i)
  } else {
    df <- cbind(ID=n, i, f)
  }
  return(df)
}

# BUILD DF LIST
df_list <- Map(proc_merge, info_list, filings_list, names(info_list))

# ROW BIND ALL ELEMENTS AND RESET ROWNAMES
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
row.names(final_df) <- NULL
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/RGGPPN1062)